# Fast Circular buffer in python than the one using deque?

Tags: python, numpy

I am implementing circular buffer in python using collections.deque to use it for some calculations. This is my original code:

```
clip=moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip('file.mp4')
clip_size= clip.size[::-1]
Depth=30
dc=5
TempKern = # some array of size Depth
RingBuffer=deque(np.zeros(clip_size, dtype=float),maxlen=NewDepth)
modified_clip = clip.fl_image(new_filtered_output)
modified_clip.write_videofile('output.mp4'))

def new_filtered_output(image):
   global RingBuffer
   inter_frame=somefunction(image)# inter_frame and image shape is same as clip_size
   RingBuffer.append(inter_frame)
   # Apply kernel
   Output =  dc + np.sum([np.asarray(RingBuffer)[j]*TempKern[j] for j in range(Depth)],axis=0)
   return Output
```

Is this the fastest way possible? I have heard that numpy roll is an option. But I don't know how to make it behave like the above code?

Comment: what's a realistic size for this buffer?  Contents always fixed size 2d arrays like this?

Comment: The buffer I plan to use is (30, 1080, 720). So, the maxlen of buffer is 30 here

Comment: the sum part can be steamlined with `np.einsum('ijk,i',np.array(buf),TempKern)` or `tensordot` equivalent.

Comment: yes, the maxlen will be the depth.

Comment: The edited code doesn't make make sense and doesn't run either. I think you are over-simplifying the case. If you are not actually performing those `some calculations` in your use-case at any line in the posted code, state the same there.

Comment: @Divakar I wasnt sure why its not working. But here is my original code which is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the ring buffer as a numpy array, by doubling the size and slicing:

```
clipsize = clip.size[::-1]
depth = 30
ringbuffer = np.zeros((2*depth,) + clipsize)

framecounter = 0

def new_filtered_output(image):
   global ringbuffer, framecounter
   inter_frame = somefunction(image)

   idx = framecounter % depth
   ringbuffer[idx] = ringbuffer[idx + depth] = inter_frame
   buffer = ringbuffer[idx + 1 : idx + 1 + depth]
   framecounter += 1

   # Apply kernel
   output =  dc + np.sum([buffer[j]*kernel[j] for j in range(depth)], axis=0)
   return output
```

Now you don't have convert the deque into a numpy array every frame (and every loop iteration..).

As mentioned in the comments, you can apply the kernel more effeciently:

```
output = dc + np.einsum('ijk,i->jk', buffer, kernel)
```

Or:

```
output = dc + np.tensordot(kernel, buffer, axes=1)
```

Comment: This answer really speeded up things. Thanks. Can you look at my other question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686611/fast-cubic-spline-output-computation-given-segments-and-coefficients

Answer (score 3):

I noticed you changed the code above, but your original code was:

```
def one():
    TempKern=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
    depth=len(TempKern)
    buf=deque(np.zeros((2,3)),maxlen=5)
    for i in range(10):
        buf.append([[i,i+1,i+2],[i+3,i+4,i+5]])
    total=  + np.sum([np.asarray(buf)[j]*TempKern[j] for j in range(depth)],axis=0)
    print('total')
    print(total)
    return total
```

You can simplify things greatly and make it run quite a bit faster if you first flatten the arrays for the computation.

```
def two():
    buf = np.zeros((5,6), dtype=np.int32)
    for idx, i in enumerate(range(5, 10)):
        buf[idx] = np.array([[i,i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4,i+5]], dtype=np.int32)
    return (buf.T * np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])).sum(axis=1).reshape((2,3))
```

The second implementation returns the same values and runs about 4x faster on my machine

```
one()

>> [[115 130 145]
    [160 175 190]]   ~ 100µs / loop

two()

>> array([[115, 130, 145],
          [160, 175, 190]])    ~~ 26µs / loop
```

You can further simplify and parameterize this as such:

```
def three(n, array_shape):
    buf = np.zeros((n,array_shape[0]*array_shape[1]), dtype=np.int32)
    addit = np.arange(1, n+1, dtype=np.int32)
    for idx, i in enumerate(range(n, 2*n)):
        buf[idx] = np.arange(i, i+n+1)
    return (buf.T * addit).sum(axis=1).reshape(array_shape)
```

`three(5, (2,3))`

```
    >> array([[115, 130, 145],
             [160, 175, 190]])   ~ 17µs / loop
```

Note that the second and third version returns a numpy array. You can cast it to a list by using `.tolist()` if need be.

Based on your feedback - edit below:

```
def four(array_shape):
    n = array_shape[0] * array_shape[1] - 1
    buf = []
    addit = np.arange(1, n+1, dtype=np.int32)
    for idx, i in enumerate(range(n, 2*n)):
        buf.append(np.arange(i, i+n+1))
    buf = np.asarray(buf)
    summed = (buf.T * addit).sum(axis=1)
    return summed.reshape(array_shape)
```

Comment: Thanks Greg for the answer. However, the appending part is not that easy in the current version of the question. A function is used to append elements to the buffer. And I do not know in advance how many elements will be appended in total. But buffer size is fixed.

Comment: then I would say use a list instead of preallocating the buf, and just change `buf[idx] = np.arange(i, i+n+1)` into `buf[idx] = func(idx, i, n)`?  See my edit `four()`

Comment: what is buf_tmp? Appending to be doen in buf_tmp? It doesn't seem to work for me. I use : buf_tmp = np.ones(n, dtype=np.int32)
while i<10:
    buf_tmp.append(np.random.randn(2, 3).flatten())
    i+=1
print buf_tmp
buf = np.asarray(buf_tmp)
total = (buf.T * addit).sum(axis=1).reshape(array_shape). I get the following error: ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds ---> 15 total = (buf.T * addit).sum(axis=1).reshape(array_shape)

Comment: You can ignore that - it was late and I didn't remove it. Obviously your parameters have to match up to the size of the array. Anyway, I amended function `four()` for you so now you just pass in the array shape

Comment: Thanks Greg. Do you mind looking at my other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686611/fast-cubic-spline-output-computation-given-segments-and-coefficients