# Fast Cubic Spline output computation given segments and coefficients?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a cubic spline activation function with 6 segments. The breaks (length= 7 (6+1)) and the coefficients are known (shape=(6L,4L)). This cubic spline works on the input relative from the breakpoints, and not the absolute values. Here is my output calculation method with some sample data:

```
def CubSpline(cs,x):
   breaks=cs['breaks']
   coefs=cs['coefs']
   pieces=cs['pieces']
   if x <= breaks[0] :
      return coefs[0][3]
   elif x >= breaks[pieces] :
      ind=pieces-1
      diff=breaks[ind+1]-breaks[ind]
   else :
      ind=0
      while x > breaks[ind+1] :
         ind += 1
      diff=x-breaks[ind]
   y=coefs[ind][3]+coefs[ind][2]*diff + coefs[ind][1]*diff*diff + coefs[ind][0]*diff*diff*diff
   return y

vcubspline=np.vectorize(CubSpline)

breaks=5*np.sort(np.random.randn(7))
coefs=np.random.randn(6,4)
pieces=6
cs=dict()
cs['pieces']=pieces
cs['breaks']=breaks
cs['coefs']=coefs
arr=np.random.randint(10,size=(500,500))

start=time.clock()
a=vcubspline2(cs,arr)
print a.shape
stop=time.clock()
print stop-start
```

I wish to know if this is the fastest way of computing the output? How to improve this?

Comment: Do you have a sample of data, and sample (expected) output from that data?

Comment: @GregJennings : Added sample data

Comment: Maybe `numpy.piecewise` will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`numpy.piecewise`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html), as suggested in a comment, leads to code that is both more efficient and more concise. The function works directly with an array x, creating arrays of conditions (inequalities involving x) and corresponding arrays of functions, then passing all to `piecewise`

```
def cubicSpline(cs, x):
    breaks = cs['breaks']
    coefs = cs['coefs']
    x = np.clip(x, breaks[0], breaks[-1])   # clip to the interval in which spline is defined
    conditions = [x <= b for b in breaks]
    functions = [coefs[0][3]] + [lambda x, c=c, b=b: c[3] + c[2]*(x-b) + c[1]*(x-b)**2 + c[0]*(x-b)**3 for c, b in zip(coefs, breaks)]
    y = np.piecewise(x, conditions, functions)
    return y

breaks = 5*np.sort(np.random.randn(7))
coefs = np.random.randn(6,4)
cs = {'breaks': breaks, 'coefs': coefs}
arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(500,500))
a = cubicSpline(cs, arr)
```

The last line executes at 53 ms (from timeit), versus 805 ms for the original version.

The `pieces` field of input dictionary was redundant, since the given breakpoints and coefficients already have that information.