# Copying 2D numpy arrays as channels of 3D numpy array efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to make multiple copies of given 2D arrays and store them as channels of a 3D numpy array. Currently, I have the following:

```
finalOut=np.zeros((800,400,3))
output_frame=np.random.randn(800,400)
for i in range(finalOut.shape[-1]):
    finalOut[:,:,i]=output_frame
```

Is this the fastest way possible?

Comment: Loop `for i in range(finalOut.shape[-1]):` - the size of the last dimension, not the number of dimensions (they just happen to both be 3).

Comment: Thanks hpaulj. Corrected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def gks(frame):
    finalOut=np.zeros((800,400,3))
    for i in range(finalOut.shape[-1]):
        finalOut[:,:,i]=frame
    return finalOut
```

For this size your code is just as good as a `tile` solution:

```
In [52]: frame = np.random.randn(800,400)
In [61]: np.allclose(gks(frame), np.tile(frame[:,:,None],[1,1,3]))
Out[61]: True

In [62]: timeit np.tile(frame[:,:,None],[1,1,3]).shape
100 loops, best of 3: 9.36 ms per loop

In [63]: timeit gks(frame).shape
100 loops, best of 3: 9.36 ms per loop
```

The `np.tile` code uses `repeat` (compiled) to make copies, and `reshape` before and after to apply that in the right shape(s).

There are various ways of using broadcasting, but they don't seem to be any faster.

```
In [70]: timeit (frame[:,:,None]+np.zeros(3)).shape
100 loops, best of 3: 11.6 ms per loop
```

Your loop fares well because the size 3 is small compared to the overall array size.

---

Here's something even faster:

```
def spl(frame):
    finalOut=np.zeros((800,400,3))
    finalOut[...]=frame[...,None]
    return finalOut

In [105]: timeit spl(frame)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.54 ms per loop
```

I was hesitant to suggest this because I thought it would be creating views, not copies.  But preliminary testing indicates that it is copying.

Comment: I agree that there is not much scope of speed gain

Comment: I found a faster one, I think

Comment: thanks hpaulj, it appears faster in general, but very insignificant speed gain I am getting.

Comment: @praveen I already did. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686551/fast-circular-buffer-in-python-than-the-one-using-deque . I accepted one answer too. The output in the answer is I am trying to replicate for the 3 channels

Answer (score 1):

Look into using [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy.tile).

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6]])
>>> np.tile(a, (3, 1, 1))
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],
       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],
       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
```

Of course, this puts channels in the 0'th axis, so you probably want to move that using [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) afterwards:

```
>>> b = np.tile(a, (3, 1, 1))
>>> np.transpose(b, (1, 2, 0))
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]],
       [[4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6]]])
>>> np.transpose(b, (1, 2, 0)).shape
(2, 3, 3)
```

**Test**

```
>>> d = np.transpose(b, (1, 2, 0))
>>> c = np.zeros((2, 3, 3))
>>> for i in range(3): c[:, :, i] = a[:, :]
>>> np.allclose(c, d)
True
```

---

The fastest possible option is often to use numpy [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), which allows you to create a new axis, and not use it until necessary. For example:

```
>>> b = a[:, :, np.newaxis]
>>> b.shape
(2, 3, 1)
>>> b = b * np.array([1, 0, 0])   # Set G and B channels to 0.
>>> b
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [2, 0, 0],
        [3, 0, 0]],    
       [[4, 0, 0],
        [5, 0, 0],
        [6, 0, 0]]])
```

Then, the new 3D-array isn't even constructed until an operation is performed on the channels. But it takes some getting used to...

Comment: not sure if np.rollaxis(b, 0, 3) output is what I want. Although the shapes are proper now, but when I subtract the finalOut from my method and your method, the absolute difference is huge

Comment: @GKS I've edited my answer to use transpose instead, and I've added a test to show you that it works. Does that help?

Comment: It does help, however, its still not faster. Thanks a lot though for teaching

Comment: @GKS Chances are, this is not the bottleneck in your code. If you could share the rest of your program in a separate question, we might be able to help speed up the other operations.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`np.dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
import numpy as np

def copy_dstack(frame):
    return np.dstack((frame,)*3)

def copy_for(frame):
    arr = np.zeros(shape=frame.shape + (3,))
    for i in range(arr.shape[-1]):
        arr[:, :, i] = frame
    return arr

def copy_tile(frame):
    return np.tile(frame[:, :, None], [1, 1, 3])

def copy_broadcasting(frame):
    arr = np.zeros(shape=frame.shape + (3,))
    arr[...] = frame[..., None]
    return arr
```

According to my tests the approaches proposed by @hpaulj and @Praveen are slower than yours, whereas mine gives you a negligible speed gain:

```
In [244]: frame = np.random.randn(800, 400)

In [245]: %timeit copy_dstack(frame)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.07 ms per loop

In [246]: %timeit copy_for(frame)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.1 ms per loop

In [247]: %timeit copy_tile(frame)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.8 ms per loop

In [248]: %timeit copy_broadcasting(frame)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.71 ms per loop
```

I also checked that all the methods yield the same result:

```
In [249]: np.allclose(copy_dstack(frame), copy_for(frame))
Out[249]: True

In [250]: np.allclose(copy_for(frame), copy_tile(frame))
Out[250]: True

In [251]: np.allclose(copy_tile(frame), copy_broadcasting(frame))
Out[251]: True
```